# Why cascade does not work if we define it on children side (mappedBy)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let say I have 2 models:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  
  @Basic(optional = false)
  private String name;
  
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
  private List<Product> products;
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  
  @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
  private List<Category> categories;
}
```

When I try to persist a product with some categories inside like this:

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner t(CategoryRepository categoryRepository, ProductRepository productRepository) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            categoryRepository.save(new Category(null, "name 1", null));
            categoryRepository.save(new Category(null, "name 2", null));
            categoryRepository.save(new Category(null, "name 3", null));

            List<Category> all = categoryRepository.findAll();
            all.add(new Category(null, "$$$", null));

            productRepository.save(new Product(null, all));
            
        }
    };
}
```

It does work and I can see the data in the "join table"
[image]

But if I revert the process, mean `persist a category with some products inside` like this:

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner t(CategoryRepository categoryRepository, ProductRepository productRepository) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            productRepository.save(new Product());
            productRepository.save(new Product());
            productRepository.save(new Product());

            List<Product> all = productRepository.findAll();
            all.add(new Product());

            categoryRepository.save(new Category(null, "%%%%%%%%", all));
        }
    };
}
```

Although it does not throw any error/exception, but the result is not my expectation. I think it should be like the first case - the "join table" should have some rows - but actually just `category` and `product` contain rows.

Could you guy explain to me why the second case does not work? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JPA spec, changes to the `mappedBy` side of a bidirectional association are not made persistent. One side of the association, the “owning” side, has responsibility for persisting changes. The “unowned” side is in some sense read-only.

Comment: could you share the document link?

Comment: I’m pretty sure your google works just as well as mine.

Comment: the problem is: I don't know the keyword. If I use something like "jpa", "mappedBy", "cascade", google return me a lot of tutorial, but not official document of jpa/hibernate. If you have it, please share to me

Comment: Seriously? https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/